# JSON AJAX Struts2 jQuery fields not populating the second time IE 11 fixed

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, struts2

**Fixed**: Don't use jQuery() function when calling struts2 action. Use the "onchange" or "onclick" tag and call a javascript function then call the .ajax method. This will work using IE11.

**EDIT**: This seems to be a browser issue. Basically the action is triggered every time in Chrome but not in IE 11. I'm only allowed to deploy this on IE 11 so need a fix please.

Thanks

I've got the dropdown fields to populate given a list of values. But after I call the struts action which from ajax the second time, or anytime after the there is no response the second time. So I'm able to see "ajax called" and the dropdown value selected (fiscalYearName). But say I click it again, it doesn't execute the action. Maybe there is a property tag I'm missing?

struts.xml

```
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default">
    <action name="queryOppName" class="gov.hud.pih.action.AjaxGrantAppAction">
       <result type="json">
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
       </result>
   </action>
</package>
```

AjaxGrantAppAction.java:

```
private String fiscalYearName;

public String execute() {

    System.out.println("ajax called");

    System.out.println(fiscalYearName);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fiscalYear').change(function(event) {
    var fiscalyear = $("select#fiscalYear").val();
    $.getJSON('queryOppName', {
      fiscalYearName : fiscalyear
    }, function(jsonResponse) {

    var select = $('#opportunityName');

    select.find('option').remove();
    $.each(jsonResponse.grantMap, function(key, value) {
      $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(select);
    });
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

jsp:

```
<s:select  name="fiscalYear" id="fiscalYear" label="Fiscal Year"      

   list="{'2008,'2009','2010','2011','2012'}"  ></s:select>
```

Comment: So, what's happening then?

Comment: hey Roman, so this seems to be a browser issue with jQuery ajax struts2. The action is called every time in chrome but not in IE 11. Any help?
thanks

Comment: The answers section below where you can post your own answer.